# Does dplyr 0.8.5 provide `unnest()`?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
> library(dplyr)

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

> help(unnest)
No documentation for ‘unnest’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??unnest’

> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘0.8.5’
```

I have installed dplyr and loaded it, but `unnest()` seems missing. Does dplyr 0.8.5 provide `unnest()`?  How shall I have access to `unnest()`?

Comment: try `tidyr`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unnest` function is apart of the `tidyr` R package.

Install the `tidyr` package with `install.packages("tidyr")` and then call the library at the beginning of your code with `library(tidyr)`.

I hope this helps!